# Connection between Node-Red running in IBM Cloud and sqlite in localsystem

Tags: sqlite, ibm-cloud, iot, node-red

I am new to Node-Red and SQL Lite, I am trying to connect my Node-Red app running in IBM cloud to the sqlite running in my local pc, I tried to connect by giving the database location like "C:\sqlite\db\SmartBar_DB.db", but is not working.

[image: sqlite-node]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Node-RED is running in the IBM Cloud then it has absolutely no access to files on your local computer.

You will not be able to connect from the IBM Cloud application to anything on your local computer.

Comment: Is it possible to run sqlite in IBM Cloud?

Comment: No, the filesystem is not persistent on IBM Cloud. They do offer other databases as a service, but these are likely to charge for access.